# Data columns not binding with the element of HTML table

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

I'm trying to display data from my PostgreSQL into an HTML table using Ajax and PHP. But it seems that the data I am getting is not binding into the columns element of HTML table, I just get back a Json string [image: (look like this)] .

How can I am binding `id`, `employee_name`, `employee_salary` and `employee_age` column with 'td' element of HTML table

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top:50px;">
        <table id="employee_grid" class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="emp_body">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Ajax** (binding column with element of HTML table):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Handling get employee */
    function get_employee() {
      $.ajax({        
        type : 'GET',
        url  : 'response.php?action=list',
        success : function(response){
          response = JSON.parse(response);
            var tr;
                $('#emp_body').html('');
                $.each(response, function( index, emp ) {
                tr = $('');
                    tr.append("" + emp.id + "");
                    tr.append("" + emp.employee_name + "");
                    tr.append("" + emp.employee_salary + "");
                    tr.append("" + emp.employee_age + "");
    
                    var action = 
                    "<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>";
                    action += "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_model'>Edit</a>";
                    action += "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Delete</a></div>";
                    tr.append(action);
                    $('#emp_body').append(tr);
            });
        }
      });
    }
    
    //initialize method on load
    function init() {
        get_employee();
    }
    init();
});
```

**PHP** (query data from PostgreSQL)

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
 
$params = $_REQUEST;
$action = isset($params['action']);
$params['action'] !='' ? $params['action'] : 'list';
$empCls = new Employee();
 
switch($action) {
    case 'list':
        $empCls->getEmployees();
    break;
    default:
    return;
}

class Employee {
    protected $conn;
    protected $data = array();
    function __construct() {

    $db = new dbObj();
    $connString =  $db->getConnstring();
        $this->conn = $connString;
    }
    
    function getEmployees() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $queryRecords = pg_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to fetch employees data");
        $data = pg_fetch_all($queryRecords);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is td in your table structure?

Comment: I tried to create it in Ajax code

Comment: Did you try to set dataType: 'json' in your ajax config object?

Comment: I use `response = JSON.parse(response);` instead of `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Hi, you need to add `<tr>` and `<td>` tags while appending the responses. For example refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gmo0jkxt/)

Comment: @Swati Thank a lot, Sir. It's worked. Please post it as an answer if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `<tr>` & `<td>` tag as well while appending the responses to your table.

Changes you can add in your current code :

```
  var tr = $('<tr></tr>'); //tr tag
  //appending td >>
  tr.append("<td>" + emp.id + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_name + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_salary + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_age + "</td>");
```

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var response = [{
    "id": 1,
    "employee_name": "xyz",
    "employee_salary": 3444,
    "employee_age": 23
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "employee_name": "xyz2",
    "employee_salary": 34442,
    "employee_age": 9
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "employee_name": "xyz3",
    "employee_salary": 34443,
    "employee_age": 2
  }
] //this is dummy data


$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Handling get employee */
  function get_employee() {
    /* $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'response.php?action=list',
       success: function(response) {
         response = JSON.parse(response);*/
    $('#emp_body').html('');
    $.each(response, function(index, emp) {
      var tr = $('<tr></tr>'); //tr tag
      //appending td >>
      tr.append("<td>" + emp.id + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_name + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_salary + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + emp.employee_age + "</td>");

      var action =
        "<td><div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>";
      action += "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_model'>Edit</a>";
      action += "<a href='#' target='_blank' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Delete</a></div></td>";
      tr.append(action);
      $('#emp_body').append(tr);
    });

    /*}
    });*/
  }
  //initialize method on load
  function init() {
    get_employee();
  }
  init();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-top:50px;">
  <table id="employee_grid" class="table" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="emp_body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```